# Cna't access nested objects in reactjs even after a load conditional

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, render

I'm getting an error while I'm trying to access a nested object in ReactJs.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

I've added a loading  conditional and iI can access the object with the nested info, but I get the error when I try to access the info itself.

```
{content: "sdfgsdfgsdfg"}
{date: "2020-06-04T00:32:09.192Z"}
{tags: ["test"]}
{title: "Heres the dang title"}
{userId:  
    {date: "2019-08-27T23:27:42.945Z"},
    {email: "gloob@email.com"},
    {name: "gloob"},
    {_id: "5d65bc6e4402213647f8704b"}
}
```

I'm using redux so this is my reducer

```
case FETCH_BLOG_ID:
            const blogPostId = action.payload;
            var blogPostToEdit = {};
            state.blogPosts.map(blogPost => {
                if (blogPost._id == blogPostId) {
                    blogPostToEdit = blogPost;
                }
            })
            return {
                ...state,
                blogPostToEdit,
                isLoaded: true
            }
```

and this is the render where the error is thrown

```
render() {
        if (this.props.isLoading === false) {
            <div>...loading</div>
        }
        const { title, content, tags, date } = this.props.blogPostToEdit;
        const parsedDate = new Date(date);
        console.log(this.props.blogPostToEdit.userId.name)
```

Comment: In the reducer you have `isLoaded`, but in the component you use `isLoading`. Does it get renamed somewhere? The names imply different things, but with the context given I'm wondering if they are supposed to be referring to the same value? The `return` is also missing inside that conditional, is they a typo too?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I went and fixed it and now I'm getting an error that `isLoaded` is undefined

Comment: Without seeing more of the code I can't guess any further than that. The problem could be in the reducer, mapStateToProps, or somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

in `render`  function if `isLoading` is `false` you should return `<div>...loading</div>`

```
render() {
        if (this.props.isLoading === false) {
            return <div>...loading</div>
        }
        const { title, content, tags, date } = this.props.blogPostToEdit;
        const parsedDate = new Date(date);
        console.log(this.props.blogPostToEdit.userId.name)
```

it's better to use `forEach` instead of `map` in reducer function and I suggest you keep your reducer function simple and separate logic from reducer

Comment: That's what the logic says but I'm still receiving that error. I fixed the type that some one  pointed out earlier but now I'm getting a different error that `isLoaded` is not defined

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out. After fixing the typo with `isLoaded` I realized I was mapping the state for `isLoaded` to props wrong, after fixing that it worked. Next time I'll be sure to include more of the coded. It didn't occur to me to include my mapStateToProps function. Thanks a whole bunch everyone.